# MailCore CFNetwork.framework Dependency Using Invalid Location

Tags: objective-c, mailcore

I'm new to Xcode and Objective C development and I'm attempting to import the github MailCore 
[InboxListener example](https://github.com/mronge/MailCore/tree/master/Examples/OSX/InboxLister) Xcode project for the Mac OSX environment.  I followed the Mac OSX instructions from [MailCore's website](http://libmailcore.com/) and the project builds but doesn't run. MailCore seems dependent on /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework which doesn't exist in my  /System/Library/Frameworks/ directory on my Mac OS X 10.7.5.

CFNetwork.framework does exist in  /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks, but why doesn't MailCore know where to find it?  How do I change the location MailCore is using?

I've tried linking CoreServices.framework and CFNetwork.framework in the Build Phases, link with binaries without success.  Same runtime error.

**Output when Running:**

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/Versions/A/CFNetwork
  Referenced from: /Users/cgray/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/InboxLister-hjoeknampqddvifxyoqwhozaricj/Build/Products/Debug/MailCore.framework/Versions/A/MailCore
  Reason: image not found
(lldb)
```

[image]

Comment: If it is a private framework try copying to the project folder and drag and drop to Xcode. Include it also in the LinkBinary with libraries section. That could be the issue here.

Comment: I think the issue has to do with the iOS/OSX projects being bundled together. This error occurs when I compile the OSX demos. But I does not occur when I compile the iOS demo.

Answer (score 2):

It was a brain teaser for me!

I resolved to set the **SDK 10.7** in **any project and targets** of your project, of Mailcore and the Libetpan library.
Then select the libetpan project in the Project navigator and check:

1. open the **CoreService.framework** and check if there is the CFNetwork.framework (look below). If it not exists your code cannot include the SDK 10.7 where CFNetwork is under the CoreService umbrella framework.
2. select "**static libetpan**" target and check in your "Link Binary With Libraries", you should found the CoreService.framework. If there isn't add it (you can also drag&drop from the Project navigator)

Clean and build, it should work!

[image]

Comment: My fix was pretty similar. I only had to change the MailCore framework and the static libetpan Mac library to have a Base SDK of 10.7. I built my target with Base SDK of 10.8 and all was well.